# Passing Variable to DoCmd.MoveSize to move Forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables, userform, max-size

I'm trying to keep the position of all forms uniform when switching between them all, but when calling the code in a function, MaxSize isn't working.

This records the WindowLeft and WindowTop value in a table, and I run this just before any form closes.

```
Function recordFormPosition(frm As Form)

On Error GoTo Error
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

                          'Table           Field          Window position
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE FormPosition SET FormTop = """ & frm.WindowTop & """"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE FormPosition SET FormLeft = """ & frm.WindowLeft & """"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Function

debug
Error:
MsgBox ("Error")
End Function
```

This function is called on any Form_Load to set the form to the position recorded in the table

```
Function setFormPosition(frm As Form)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim tp As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lft As DAO.Recordset
    Dim wintop As String
    Dim winleft As String

    'Sets location of form
    wintop = "SELECT FormTop FROM FormPosition WHERE ID = 1"
    winleft = "SELECT FormLeft FROM FormPosition WHERE ID = 1"
    
    Set tp = db.OpenRecordset(wintop)
    Set lft = db.OpenRecordset(winleft)
    
    frm.DoCmd.MoveSize tp.Fields(0).Value, lft.Fields(0).Value
    
End Function
```

And I use this to call the function and pass the form variable

```
Call setFormPosition([Form])      or     Call recordFormPosition([Form])
```

**My problem is with this line:**

```
DoCmd.MoveSize tp.Fields(0).Value, lft.Fields(0).Value
```

Where do I pass on the frm. variable? I keep getting the error: An Expression in argument 2 has an invalid value, but I'm passing 2 intergers from a table that is formatted to numbers. I did some debugging and passed tp.Fields(0).Value & lft.Fields(0).Value in msgbox's and can verify that they are returning numbers, so the only explaination is that it has to be a focus issue

Comment: `DoCmd.MoveResize` works only on the active window.  It takes no argument for a form name.

Comment: Great! So what's the work around, just execute the code in the forms instead? Can you pass variables to Move size?

Comment: Of course can use variables for MoveSize arguments - that's what your code does by referencing fields. I just set forms to open centered in app window.

Comment: One issue is likely that the function is called at `OnLoad` which fires before the form is active. Run `MoveSize` once the form is active. Take a look here for sequence of events: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9